# Using Comparator.comparing for sorting an object by a list of objects and then by a second property

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I initially sorted a list by an attribute of an object (let's say a *User* by its *firstName*) with:

```
Collections.sort(userList, (u1, u2) -> (u1.getFirstName()).compareTo(u2.getFirstName()));
```

which I was able to replace with:

```
Collections.sort(userList, Comparator.comparing(User::getFirstName));
```

But now the *User* has a list of *Roles* with a *roleName* each and I want to sort the list by the *roleName* of the *Role* of the *User*. I came up with this:

```
Collections.sort(userList, (u1, u2) -> (u1.getUserRoles().get(0).getRoleName()).compareTo(u2.getUserRoles().get(0).getRoleName()));
```

which seems to work fine.

In the IDE, there is now the message: *Can be replaced with Comparator.comparing ...*, but I do not know how to exactly do this. Is this even possible? Something like this don't work:

```
Collections.sort(userList, Comparator.comparing(User::getUserRoles.get(0).getRoleName());
```

How can I sort this with *Comparator.comparing*?

And after sorting by *roleName*, how is it possible to sort by the *firstName* as a second property?

Comment: What IDE are you using? When you see a hint like that in IntelliJ, you can simply hit `alt + enter` and it will do it for you.

Comment: Don't feel you _have to_ take the IDE's suggestion just because it's being offered. And don't be too surprised if, after you've changed your code as the IDE suggested (or, better yet, made the IDE do the change), the IDE then suggests changing it back to what you originally had!

Comment: As law of Demeter says you shall not call user.getUserRoles.get(0).getRoleName() but rather implement a getUserRoleName (or getUsersFirstRoleName) on the User. You can then use Comparator.comparing(...).thenComparing(...) chain. Given that user might not have a role at all you also might consider looking into Comparator.nullsLast / Comparator.nullsFirst.

Comment: @Michal: I wasn't aware of that, but it sounds logic. What if the user can have more than one roles?

Comment: @Michal: Could you please provide an example of avoiding the law of Demeter?

Comment: With 'avoiding' do you mean 'conforming to'? According to the law of Demeter a given object shall talk only to objects it collaborates direct with. Translated into Java,  an expression with more then one . (like a.getB().getC()) breaks the law of Demeter. I tend to conform to that rule on my object model, on utility methods like the discussed comparison chain or Mockito setups are the chained call ok for me.

Comment: Of course the user / roles discussion here does not cover the problem that an user have 0..n roles, from that point of view is the sentence *But now the User has a list of Roles with a roleName each and I want to sort the list by the roleName of the Role of the User.*  broken. What is the role of the user if he has a 10 roles? And if he has no role at all?

Comment: A *user* always has at least one *role*. I do sort all *roles* of a *user* alphabetically (e.g.: "admin" > "editor" > "viewer"), and then by the first (`get(0)`), so I have all admins at first, then all editors and so on and after that I additionally sorted by *lastName* and *firstName*. I will try to have a look to conform to the law of demeter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use a method reference in this case, but you can use a lambda expression:

```
Collections.sort(userList, Comparator.comparing(u -> u.getUserRoles().get(0).getRoleName()));
```

To sort by two properties:

```
Collections.sort(userList, Comparator.comparing((Function<User,String>)u -> u.getUserRoles().get(0).getRoleName())
                                     .thenComparing(User::getFirstName));
```

or

```
Collections.sort(userList, Comparator.comparing((User u) -> u.getUserRoles().get(0).getRoleName())
                                     .thenComparing(User::getFirstName));
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to add *()*: `Collections.sort(userList, Comparator.comparing(u -> u.getUserRoles().get(0).getRoleName()));`

Now I'm struggling with *thenComparing*, because I would then like to sort the list by the first name. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @Eran: The sorting by two properties does not work. It gives me *Cannot resolve method 'getUserRoles()'*.

Comment: @manu It seems the compiler has some problem with type inference. I tried a similar sorting (of different elements), and casting the lambda expression to the correct type seemed to help. See edit

Comment: This works. I am now sorting first by the *userRoles*'s *roleName*, then by the *lastName* and then by the *firstName* with `Collections.sort(userList, Comparator.comparing((Function<User, String>) u -> u.getUserRoles().get(0).getRoleName()).thenComparing(User::getLastName).thenComparing(User::getFirstName));`

Thank you very much!